# How to parse content within <script> with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

For example in a webpage I have somewhere:

```
<script id="ajaxify-data" type="application/json">
{"key1":123,"key2":333}
</script>
```

Can I use javascript to parse it? (specifically, the ajaxify-data)

jQuery `$("#ajaxify-data")` just doesn't work here..

Edit: The website that I wanted to crawl actually is more complex than the simple example given above...

https://discuss.leetcode.com/unread looks like the web source, although containing `ajaxify-data` tag, it actually renders the data in ajax result instead of storing it in the actual ajax tag above.

This is what I get in the console:

```
> document.getElementById('ajaxify-data')
null
```

The webpage screenshot:
[image: https://discuss.leetcode.com/ screenshot]

Comment: Seems to work fine for me -> https://jsfiddle.net/yqLt7rv6/

Comment: Are you ajaxing the source of the site? So that you are dealing with a string of HTML content?

Comment: Did u have a chance try to get script?

Answer (score 6):

Just `JSON parse` the innerHTML of the script tag.

**Plain JavaScript:**

```js
var json = JSON.parse(
  document.getElementById('ajaxify-data').innerHTML
);

console.log(json);
console.log(json.key1);
```

```html
<script id="ajaxify-data" type="application/json">
  { "key1": 123, "key2": 333 }
</script>
```

---

**Or with jQuery:**

```js
var json = JSON.parse($('#ajaxify-data').html())

console.log(json);
console.log(json.key1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="ajaxify-data" type="application/json">
  { "key1": 123, "key2": 333 }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, very complete! Do you have any idea about parsing <https://discuss.leetcode.com/unread> in specific? There's a `ajaxify-data` in <view-source:https://discuss.leetcode.com/unread> but vanilla / jquery JS cannot get the tag

Comment: You might need to include a screenshot in order for me to understand what you are looking for specifically.

Comment: added a screenshot; please check in the question! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
    $('#ajaxify-data').html()
    $('#ajaxify-data').text()
```

works for me)

Comment: Thanks, very complete! Do you have any idea about parsing <https://discuss.leetcode.com/unread> in specific? There's a `ajaxify-data` in <view-source:https://discuss.leetcode.com/unread> but vanilla / jquery JS cannot get the tag

Comment: @SeanLao It is not possible to get <script> tag that is outside of document, according to specification. As a workaround I would send additional ajax request to the same server and get all code with html            $.ajax({
  url: 'https://discuss.leetcode.com/unread',
  success: function(data){console.log(data)}
}); and then you will have to parse to distinguish html and script

Comment: Write if you have questions

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to get the contents of an inline `script` element:

- `textContent`: returns the text content of a Node
- `innerHTML`: returns the HTML content of an Element
- `text`: returns the text content of a HTMLScriptElement

Then, if it contains JSON, you can parse it with `JSON.parse`.